# How to initiate a download on the client site with jquery and rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, download

I have the following code in a controller of my rails4 application:

```
# resolve the soft links and archive all photos for the current download
archived_photos = archive_current_download_photos(current_downloads_dir)

respond_to do |format|

  if !File.exists?(archived_photos)
    format.json { 
      render :nothing => true, :status => 500
    }
  else
    format.json {
      send_file(archived_photos, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => "photos.zip", :type => 'application/zip')
    }
  end

end
```

And the handling in javascript:

```
   download photos request

   ajax_download = (valuesToSubmit, download_url, http_method) ->

   # AJAX
   $.ajax
    type: http_method
    url: download_url #sumbits it to the given url of the form
    data: valuesToSubmit # form
    dataType: "json"
    error: (error) ->
      console.log("DEBUG: error")
      return
    success: (data) ->

      console.log("DEBUG: success")
      return

   return false
```

When this function going called I don't get a download, but I see the data is downloaded.

How is it possible to force Chrome to start the download (without using link_to, but rather to start download immediately after response)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `window.location` to the force download url path of your rails app.?

I guess this should work as new page won't be loaded and force download will pop up the file.

Comment: could you explain more detailed about the window.location - to do it in the ajax success? how?

Comment: you mean: add `window.location.href = <url to the file sent back with ajax>` ?

Comment: On the success callback, set this, `window.location = 'http://download_url`. It will redirect the user but it shouldn't be apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a file download with an ajax call. I think Chrome supports it, but you won't get a reliable cross-browser solution working IMO.

Your best best is to send the user to another page, either using `window.location`, or a link like:

```
<a href='download_url' target='_blank'>click</a>
```